# Traefik too many redirects in Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am trying to set up Traefik as my application's load balancer in Kubernetes. I was able to successfully set it up on Minikube, but things are slightly different in production.

Using some network policies, traffic comes in through our org's PLB, which I want to reach Traefik. Based on rules, it should redirect to the corresponding service.

I can view the Traefik dashboard with the configuration below, but I get **too many redirects** on whoami at abc.com/ms/whoami

**Infrastructure:**
Orgs PLB > Traefik LB > Role based routing > Microservice A/B/C...

**Part of configurations**

*traefik.yaml*

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      name: websecure
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard
spec:
  tls: {}
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure  
  routes:
  - match: Host(`traefik-abc.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/services/traefik`) || PathPrefix(`/api`))
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: api@internal
      kind: TraefikService
    middlewares: 
      - name: basic-auth
        name: stripprefix-traefik
---  
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-abc.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "org.plb"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: traefik
    servicePort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "org.plb"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: traefik
    servicePort: 80
```

**whoami.yaml**

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: containous/whoami
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: whoami
---  
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  tls: {}
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`abc.com`) && PathPrefix(`/ms/whoami`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
```

**logs**

```sh
- - [13/Aug/2020:23:56:09 +0000] "GET /ms/whoami HTTP/1.1" 301 17 "-" "-" 114 "web-to-websecure@internal" "-" 0ms
- - [13/Aug/2020:23:56:09 +0000] "GET /ms/whoami HTTP/1.1" 301 17 "-" "-" 115 "web-to-websecure@internal" "-" 0ms
- - [13/Aug/2020:23:56:09 +0000] "GET /ms/whoami HTTP/1.1" 301 17 "-" "-" 116 "web-to-websecure@internal" "-" 0ms
.....
.....
- - [13/Aug/2020:23:56:09 +0000] "GET /ms/whoami HTTP/1.1" 301 17 "-" "-" 128 "web-to-websecure@internal" "-" 0ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the logs on the client too . It could be that your whoami application is redirecting from `/ms/whoami` to `/ms/whoami/` and then your external load balancer from `/ms/whoami/` to `/ms/whoami`.

Or it could be that your application/microservice is redirecting from `/ms/whoami` to something else like `/` and then your load balancer is redirecting that back to `/ms/whoami`.  (You can also try `stripprefix-traefik` middleware if this is the case)

The above are just examples, as you can see it's evident you have a loop .

✌️